# Sharepoint list: offer selections in one field based on the value of another field in the same list?

Tags: 2010, list

I have two Sharepoint lists. One would contain some invoice details and the other list would contain some lookup data to spare repeated data entry for the user.

For example, when entering an invoice, one could select a category (like "conference", "food") and the associated data (tax, etc) could be picked up automatically from the lookup list.

I figured that if each category would contain only one possible way to enter the details, all I needed to do was a unique category field in the lookup table and do the lookup in the invoice list based on that.

Now, my issue is that for each category I can have multiple possible choices. So let's say that I have 20 possible tax to choose from, but for food, only 2 or 3 would apply. So the plan would be that if the user selects "food" from the category list, the form would offer them to select only from the two possible taxes instead of 20.

Is there any way to do this?

I don't think lookup fields would be good for that as those are like foreign keys in a normal database I guess.

Answer (score 0):

In some cases it is possible to use a managed metadata field with a proper tree like structure , however that will require that you can come up with a good name for the various taxes otherwise it will be very confusing